# How does one increase precision in C++ templates in a template typename-dependent manner?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a templated math function which takes two values, does some math to them, and returns a value of the same type.

```
template <typename T>
T math_function(T a, T b) {
  LongT x = MATH_OP1(a,b);
  return MATH_OP2(x,a);
}
```

I want to store intermediate values (in x) in a type which is basically the long version of T (above, called LongT). So, if T is float, I want x to be a double; and if T is an int, I want x to be a long int.

Is there some way to accomplish this? I tried `enable_if`, but it seems that I would really need an `enable_if_else`.

I'd prefer to have the compiler figure out what to use for LongT on its own. I'd rather not have to specify it when I call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a type mapping that will yield the needed type:

```
template <typename T> struct long_type;
template <> struct long_type<int> {
   typedef long type;
};
template <> struct long_type<float> {
   typedef double type;
};
```

And then use that metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
T math_function(T a, T b) {
  typename long_type<T>::type x = MATH_OP1(a,b);
  return static_cast<T>(MATH_OP2(x,a));
}
```

With this particular implementation, your template will fail to compile for any type other than the ones for which you have provided the `long_type` trait. You might want to provide a generic version that will just map to the itself, so that if the input is `long long int` that is what is used (assuming no larger type in your architecture).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the default look like?

Comment: @mohawkjohn: The base template would be *defined* (in the answer it is only declared) as `template <typename T> struct long_type { typedef T type; };`, that is, *for any type for which we know no larger type, use that type internally*

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't need to handle `T=long` for example, just create traits for `int` and `float`:

```
template <typename T>
struct LongT;

template <>
struct LongT<int>
{
    typedef long value_type;
};

template <>
struct LongT<float>
{
    typedef double value_type;
};

template <typename T>
T math_function(T a, T b) {
  typename LongT<T>::value_type x = MATH_OP1(a,b);
  return MATH_OP2(x,a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can use `auto` keyword to retrieve type of the `MATH_OP`. It is safe and handled by compiler.

```
auto x = MATH_OP1(a,b);
```

Comment: I don't think `auto` is the solution. My understanding is that he wants to promote the types to a larger type, perform the operations there (avoiding overflows) and then push the solution back to the original type. For example: `average( MAX_INT, MAX_INT)` could be implemented as `int average( int a, int b ) { long long _a = a, _b = b; return static_cast<int>( (_a+_b)/2 ); }`. In this case, `auto` would not resolve to `long long` but rather to `int` with the intermediate value potentially overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T> struct LongT  {typedef T type;}

template<> struct LongT<int8_t>    {typedef int16_t type;}
template<> struct LongT<int16_t>   {typedef int32_t type;}
template<> struct LongT<int32_t>   {typedef int64_t type;}
template<> struct LongT<int64_t>   {typedef intmax_t type;}
// same for unsigned ...

template<> struct LongT<float>     {typedef double type;}
// template<> struct LongT<double> {typedef long double type;}
```

Used like so:

```
typename LongT<T>::type  x;
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm actually using your code almost verbatim in NMatrix (Ruby matrix library), but I have to give the check-mark to one of the people who answered first.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own specialisations of your own structure, or use something like

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void func(const T& f, const T& s)
{
   typename std::conditional
   <
      std::is_same<T, float>::value,
      double,
      typename std::conditional
      <
        std::is_same<T, int>::value,
        long,
        void
      >::type
   >::type X(f + s);
   (void)X;
}

int main()
{
   func(1, 1);
   func(1.0f, 1.0f);
   func(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/8f75236b880a3fe210a8751e485a47ed

But write your own specializations as suggest David or Mark is pretty clever.